# JSON string from server side not coming properly using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

What I am doing is, i am getting data from server side using `mvc`. The data is properly coming in return part.
But when I m debugging in the client side, I am only getting the parameter value as `[`.

Below is the JSON response which I am getting.

```
[{"VENDORNAME":"ABC","VENDORCODE":"1234"},{"VENDORNAME":"Abc test","VENDORCODE":"233311"},{"VENDORNAME":"ABC 2","VENDORCODE":"12345"}]
```

But when I check in the client I get it only **[** in the parameter.

Below is that code

```
getValue: function (element) {        
        return {
            label: element.VENDORNAME,
            value: element.VENDORCODE
         };
    },
```

in `element` i only get as `[`

Please suggest where I am wrong

**update**

Here is the full code

```
var autocompleteOptions = {        

    url: function (phrase) {
        return AppConfig.PrefixURL + 'App/GetVendorData';
    },

    getValue: function () {        
        return {
            label: element.VENDORNAME,
            value: element.VENDORCODE
         };
    },      

    ajaxSettings: {
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            dataType: "json",                
        }
    },        

    preparePostData: function (data) {
        data.phrase = $("#txtAssignVendor").val();           
        return data;
    },

    requestDelay: 400
};
```

And reference link below

http://easyautocomplete.com/examples#examples-ddg

**Server code**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetVendorData(string phrase)
    {
        string strJsonData = "";
        try
        {
            Assignment ObjSAPAssign = new Assignment();
            DataTable dt = ObjSAPAssign.GetVendorList(phrase);               
            strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
            ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog("", "", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(strJsonData);
    }
```

Comment: how are you sending the JSON? how and where do you implement getValue()? your question is unclear and in need of editing

Comment: @FedeSc: See my updated question for more info

Comment: in your updated answer your getValue function is missing the arg `getValue(***element***)`. is that just a mistake here ?

Comment: nope, after adding that too it doesnt works.

Comment: @B N but where are you calling it getValue . where do you set it on response?

Comment: @FedeSc that method is defined for the autocomplete tool the OP is using.  The `getValue()` function definitely should take an `element` parameter, as described clearly in the tool documentation.

Comment: @Pointy: yes, I tried the same way but in element i m not getting proper values

Comment: The problem here is that all of the important code is in that autocomplete tool. Code in the tool issues the XHR to fetch the JSON, and code in that tool calls `getValue()`.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see the problem.

Comment: @B N You are serializing it twice that's why the error

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: so how should I do it ?

Comment: Remove the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);` line and send the object `dt` directly to `Json()` method below it will just serialize once. In short just do: `return Json(dt);`

Comment: dt cannot be send directly as it is mvc

Comment: Can you post the screenshot what are you getting inside `dt` ?

Comment: @BN I suggest you map the values of `dt`into a POCO and send it to the `Json()` method.

Comment: what is POCO ? here

Comment: @BN into a model class I mean

Comment: can u show with some code ?

Comment: @BN only if you provide the debug screenshot of what's coming inside `dt` without that I'm afraid I cant help much. Or just evaluate the line `strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);` in the quick watch window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The error was that you were serializing your `DataTable` twice, once by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and the other by `Json()` method.**

---

**Make a model class like this:**

```
public class VendorData 
{ 
    public string VENDORNAME { get; set; } 
    public string VENDORCODE { get; set; } 
}
```

---

**Here's the modified action method**

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult GetVendorData(string phrase) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        Assignment ObjSAPAssign = new Assignment(); 
        DataTable dt = ObjSAPAssign.GetVendorList(phrase); 
        List<VendorData> vendorList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new VendorData 
        { 
            VENDORNAME = row.Field<string>("VENDORNAME"), 
            VENDORCODE = row.Field<string>("VENDORCODE") 
        }).ToList();

        // Serializing only once 
        return Json(vendorList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "GetVendorData", ex.Message); 
        ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog("", "", "GetVendorData", ex.Message); 
        return Json(new object(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    } 
}
```

---

**and finally in the client side:**

```
var autocompleteOptions = { 

url: function (phrase) { 
    return AppConfig.PrefixURL + 'App/GetVendorData'; 
}, 

getValue: "VENDORNAME", 

template: { 
    type: "description", 
    fields: { 
    description: "VENDORCODE" 
    } 
}, 

list: { 
    match: { 
        enabled: true 
    } 
}, 

ajaxSettings: { 
    dataType: "json", 
    method: "POST", 
    data: { 
        dataType: "json", 
    } 
}, 

preparePostData: function (data) { 
    data.phrase = $("#txtAssignVendor").val(); 
    return data; 
}, 

requestDelay: 400 
};
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal mate, I will try it on Monday and let u know.. really appreciating your efforts. Upvote :)

Comment: the first one I tried and its returning it  as `{  "VENDORNAME": "ABC",  "VENDORCODE": "1234"}` but when I try to debug in client side i get it as `(2) [Array(1), Array(1)]` but nothing inside that array :(

Comment: are u their ?? need to discuss on this

Comment: @BN what are you getting as response from the API ?

Comment: response in client side is : - `(2) [Array(1), Array(1)]`. but json respnse is `{ "VENDORNAME": "ABC", "VENDORCODE": "1234"}`

Comment: @BN check in your client side are there JSON.stringify calls written anywhere ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190224/discussion-between-b-n-and-kunal-mukherjee).

Answer (score 2):

Your server code:

```
    string strJsonData = "";
    try
    {
        Assignment ObjSAPAssign = new Assignment();
        DataTable dt = ObjSAPAssign.GetVendorList(phrase);               
        strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
        ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog("", "", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(strJsonData);
```

You build the vendor list in `dt`, and then you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to build the response JSON.  However, you then serialize it *again* in that last call to `Json()`.  It should be plain

```
    return strJsonData;
```

That's why you get `[` as the first "element": the autocomplete plugin is iterating through your JSON as a *string*.  If you change that `return` statement, it will properly receive your actual table.

*edit* — I'm pretty sure that the above describes the problem, but my suggestion won't work because that `strJsonData` is the wrong data type (not `JsonResult`). Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980052/mvc-encode-json-to-datatables) I think this might work:  don't use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.  Instead, use plain `Json()`:

```
    DataTable dt;
    try
    {
        Assignment ObjSAPAssign = new Assignment();
        dt = ObjSAPAssign.GetVendorList(phrase);               

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
        ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog("", "", "GetVendorData", ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(dt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

(Note that I don't really know C# - the point is that you have to use `Json()` to get `JsonResult` from the `DataTable`.)

Now once that's sorted out, and the autocomplete plugin is receiving the array properly, the next thing to decide is what to do with that `getValue()` function. The plugin expects to be dealing with *strings*.  In your code, you have that function return an object, and that's just going to confuse the plugin.

I'm not sure what you need for the larger application, but the function could do something like this:

```
      getValue: function(element) {
        return element.VENDORNAME + " - " + element.VENDORCODE;
      }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190225/discussion-on-answer-by-pointy-json-string-from-server-side-not-coming-properly).

Comment: @BhargavRao: did all our discussions deleted ?